# using FFMPEG for demux and decoding of mpeg2Ts stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

i have a mpeg2ts stream captured by DVB card that contains 30 Programs (30 different PMTs) and Each program has two Specific PIDs for Audio and Video data and they are not Scrambled.
after initializing ffmpeg functions i use
    AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx and
    avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx ,filepath ,Null,NUll), after that call the function :
avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx , Null);
now i have
pFormatCtx->nb_streams = 60 streams. 30 stream are dedicated to AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO with mpeg2 codec_id and the other 30 streams are dedicated to AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO with H264 codec_id.
***Now,*** **my problem is** there are some Video streams such that their width and height are zero, in other words :
pFormatCtx ->strams[i]->codec->width = 0 ;
pFormatCtx ->strams[i]->codec->height= 0 ;
i think it's because of lack of enough bytes to decode related elementary stream (ES), but i do not know how can i set the value of sufficient bytes to read. 
is there any one to guide me to a solution ?

Comment: when i use another file as the same frequency of the last one ,which means all conditions are the same , the video streams with width and height equal zero are different form last input file.

Comment: My problem is solved by set the value of pFormatCtx ->probesize